# Is it ok to save users 70 privileges in the database users table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently developing my first *serious* web application (It's an ERP system). I'm now managing the privileges functionalities in the system and I'm planing to save the privileges along with the users data in the user table. But I'm having about more than 70 privileges that can be granted to users. I never encountered such a huge table before **in my short experience** and I don't know what could be the consequences later when I put the system in production, I also know if I did it wrong I will have very hard time editing the application later, so I thought It will be good If I asked here before I start doing it.

Is it OK to change table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `type` ENUM('admin','user'),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and adding about 70 columns like this

```
`p_insertSales` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_insertPurchases` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_insertCollections` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_deleteSales` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_deletePurchases` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_manageInventory` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_insertEntries` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_manageAccountingSystem` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_deleteEntries` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_approveEntries` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_seeFinancialReports` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_seeLedger` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_manageCashAccounts` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_insertCurrentAccounts` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_seeVisitorsMessages` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`p_seePurchaseOrders` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,

 -- ... more than 60 more privileges.
```

**Is it OK to do that In terms of performance and software design?**

Because I found doing it this way is easier for me to maintain since I'm loading the client data *anyway* at the beginning of the request processing in the front controller area I can change the privileges later (by adding new ones or removing) In one place.

Comment: That's probably more of a question for dba.stackexchange.com. You can either go that way, or add two other tables: one for roles/privileges, and a pivot table to match the two. The first way means adding columns any time you add a new privilege, the second just requires adding more data.

Comment: I guess it's *OK*, but it's not how I'd do it.

Comment: I highly highly recommend not doing it the way you are planning. Gordon's answer below is 100% right on. You may want to consider adding an extra layer in your user/privilege logic for "Role". A role would be defined with a bunch of privileges and then users would pick up roles. This makes assigning new users to roles (and gaining buckets of privileges) much easier down the road. For now though having a privilege table and a junction table between user/privilege is a great start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably not a good idea.  You should have a table with one row per privilege:

```
create table Privileges (
    privilegeId int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);
```

And a junction table:

```
create table UserPrivileges (
    userId int not null,
    privilegeId not null,
    constraint fk_UserPrivileges_userid foreign key (userid) references users(userid),
    constraint fk_UserPrivileges_privileges id foreign key (privilegeid) references users(userid)
);
```

These tables can have other columns.  For instance, `Privileges` might have other information about the privilege.  `UserPrivileges` might have the insertion/update date and who made the change.

This structure will make it easy to:

- Add new privileges
- Remove existing privileges (as a class)
- Add and remove privileges from an existing user

Comment: I was mid-answer with the same solution. This is good practice as, as G says, you can amend the list of priviledges. Personally, I would also add `validfrom` and `validto` into the `UserPriviledges` table to allow a history to be recorded

Comment: Note the default table engine should be innodb for references to work.. if your default engine is MyISAM you should add Engine = InnoDB to the create table statements explained here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-innodb-tables.html

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (possibly slower, possibly faster, but certainly more compact):

Group the permissions in some logical way.  (The only necessity is to get the number it perms in a single `SET` to be under 64.)  Then make a `SET` of granted/refused items:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
    user_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    insert_privs SET ('sales', 'purchases', 'collections', ...) NOT NULL,
    delete_privs SET ('sales', 'purchases', 'collections', ...) NOT NULL,
    ...
```

Or, the other way (if it is more logical or simplifies the app coding):

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
    user_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sales_privs     SET ('insert', 'delete', ...) NOT NULL,
    purchases_privs SET ('insert', 'delete', ...) NOT NULL,
    ...
```

(or whatever makes sense).

See `FIND_IN_SET()` as a handy tool for testing for a flag being set.

Also see boolean operators.

Comment: Thank you very much this nice and compact approach. This is the first time I see the `SET` column type but I will never forget about it.